# anchor tag is not working properly in popup div

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net

```
http://182.50.154.23/elweb/Products.aspx
```

i have a popup div 
click on any of product (say edumanager),a popup will appear with details of product. the problem is that the links on the popup div is not working(like the link for visit website) means its not redirecting us on the link given .
Please help me.
here is code :

```
<section id="Section2" class="ps-container">

            <div class="ps-header">
                <h1><img class="PopUpLogo" src="Images/ProductLogo/ProctorEye.png" /></h1>
            </div>
            <div class="ps-contentwrapper">
                <div class="ps-content">
                    <h2>ProctorEye</h2>
                    <span class="ps-price">PE</span>
                    <p>
                    ProctorEye is the next generation online testing platform. It enables interaction between proctor and remote test taker, provide amazing video conferencing facilities, works on unbelivable bandwidth etc Envisioned to be the best platform helping out people tp increase their employability, skills set and self paced adaptive learning. ProctorEye will provide support right from any test facility to real-time proctoring to collaboration to behavioral Anayltics. Stay Tuned!!
                    </p>
                    <a target="_blank" href="http://www.showmymarks.com">Visit Website</a>
                </div>

            </div><!-- /ps-contentwrapper -->
            <div class="ps-slidewrapper">
                <div class="ps-slides">
                    <div style="background-image: url('Images/ProctorEyeThumb.png'); background-size: 100% auto; background-position: 0px 98px;"></div>
                </div>
                    <div class="ProductsLink">
                        <a href="default.aspx">
                                <div  class="ProductLinkBox ProductVideo">
                                    <h3>Watch Video</h3>
                                </div>
                        </a>
                        <a href="default.aspx">
                                <div  class="ProductLinkBox ProductPpt">
                                    <h3>View Ppt</h3>
                                </div>
                        </a>
                        <a href="default.aspx">
                                <div class="ProductLinkBox ProductNote">
                                    <h3>Product Note</h3>
                                </div>
                        </a>
                        <a href="default.aspx">
                                <div  class="ProductLinkBox ProductGuide">
                                    <h3>User Guide</h3>
                                </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>


            </div><!-- /ps-slidewrapper -->

        </section>
```

Comment: Please post relevant code here

Comment: Stupid question but are you sure they are links? I mean I come across to spans with hover effects sometimes, they look like links but they are not.

Comment: check if you dont have a click event with a return false that affect all the anchors in the popups

Comment: Which link does not work? the http://www.showmymarks.com one?

Answer (score 1):

It seems default behavior of anchor tag is been prevented, so you can try putting this code at footer area:

```
$('.ps-container a').click(function(){
    return true;
});
```